# Find and replace regex that will transform every three lines of text into tab-separated text

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need help with find and replace regex that should work in Notepad++ that will transform the following:

```
Casino Win (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 275753888
725.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 946969393
-100.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 386386386
-20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 423672578
-20.00 CAD
Casino Win (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 794983683
6.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 974733783
-20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 457348836
-20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness)
October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 457358638
-20.00 CAD
```

into

```
Casino Win (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 275753888 725.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 946969393 -100.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 386386386 -20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 423672578 -20.00 CAD
Casino Win (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 794983683 6.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 974733783 -20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 457348836 -20.00 CAD
Casino Bet (Wilderness) October 6, 2023 1:10 AMID 457358638 -20.00 CAD
```

Note that there are thousands of lines of text, not just 24.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[How to merge lines every 3 rows in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/q/678046)*

Comment: To me it reads like you want to [replace `^(.+)\R(.+)\R(.)` with `$1\t$2\t$3`](https://regex101.com/r/Im6ZrY/2) (*tab separated*). Use this without the *`.` matches newline* option. Lots of very similar answers there already.

Answer (score 1):

This is working based on the sample data:

Find: `(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)(\r\n)?`
Replace: `$1 $2 $3\r\n`

Comment: Your answer only works on Windows where the line ending is CRLF.  On Linux, it won't work.

Comment: Well spotted, good to know 

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex (with `. matches newline` disabled):

```
(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)
```

which will capture the data on 3 lines, up to the newline/cr at the end of the third line, and replace that with

```
\1 \2 \3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(.*?)\R(.*?)\R(.*?)(\R|$)
Replace: $1 $2 $3\n
```